# How to take row values from one pandas dataframe and use them as reference to get values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One contains contact information for constituents. The other was created to pair up constituents that might be part of the same household.

Sample:

```
data1 = {'Household_0':['1234567','2345678','3456789','4567890'],
        'Individual_0':['1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444'],
        'Individual_1':['5555555','6666666','7777777','']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Constituent Id':['1234567','2345678','3456789','4567890',
                           '1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444',
                           '5555555','6666666','7777777'],
         'Display Name':['Clark Kent and Lois Lane','Bruce Banner and Betty Ross',
                         'Tony Stark and Pepper Pots','Steve Rogers','Clark Kent','Bruce Banner',
                         'Tony Stark','Steve Rogers','Lois Lane','Betty Ross','Pepper Pots']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Resulting in:

```
df1
  Household_0 Individual_0 Individual_1
0     1234567      1111111      5555555
1     2345678      2222222      6666666
2     3456789      3333333      7777777
3     4567890      4444444     

df2
   Constituent Id                 Display Name
0         1234567     Clark Kent and Lois Lane
1         2345678  Bruce Banner and Betty Ross
2         3456789   Tony Stark and Pepper Pots
3         4567890                 Steve Rogers
4         1111111                   Clark Kent
5         2222222                 Bruce Banner
6         3333333                   Tony Stark
7         4444444                 Steve Rogers
8         5555555                    Lois Lane
9         6666666                   Betty Ross
10        7777777                  Pepper Pots
```

I would like to take df1, reference the `Constituent Id` out of df2, and create a new dataframe that has the names of the constituents instead of their IDs, so that we can ensure they are truly family/household members.

I believe I can do this by iterating, but that seems like the wrong approach. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Essentially you want to join all the names from `df2` to replace the Id's in the 5x3 dataframe `df1`

Comment: you could just split the values that have `and` and filter the Id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `map` each column from `df1` with a series based on `df2` once `set_index` Constituent Id and select the column Display Name. Use `apply` to repeat the operation on each column.

```
print (df1.apply(lambda x: x.map(df2.set_index('Constituent Id')['Display Name'])))
                   Household_0  Individual_0 Individual_1
0     Clark Kent and Lois Lane    Clark Kent    Lois Lane
1  Bruce Banner and Betty Ross  Bruce Banner   Betty Ross
2   Tony Stark and Pepper Pots    Tony Stark  Pepper Pots
3                 Steve Rogers  Steve Rogers          NaN
```

Comment: This was concise and worked for my larger data set that didn't include Marvel characters. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipeline `melt`, `merge` and `pivot_table`.

```
df3 = (
    df1
    .reset_index()
    .melt('index')
    .merge(df2, left_on='value', right_on='Constituent Id')
    .pivot_table(values='Display Name', index='index', columns='variable', aggfunc='last')
)
print(df3)
```

outputs

```
variable                  Household_0  Individual_0 Individual_1
index                                                           
0            Clark Kent and Lois Lane    Clark Kent    Lois Lane
1         Bruce Banner and Betty Ross  Bruce Banner   Betty Ross
2          Tony Stark and Pepper Pots    Tony Stark  Pepper Pots
3                        Steve Rogers  Steve Rogers          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `.applymap()` to link the two together.

```
reference = df2.set_index('Constituent Id')['Display Name'].to_dict()
df1[df1.columns] = df1[df1.columns].applymap(reference.get)
```